# How to make this TextField always have focus

Tags: flutter, textfield

I'm using an external barcode scanner and I would like to maintain the focus after the submit, so I can scan an other barcode scanner immediately, without tapping or clicking it anymore.

The process is very simple:
The user scan a barcode, then on this barcode will be done some operations, then I would like to give focus back on the same TextField, so I can scan an other barcode without clicking on the TextField for giving that manually, I would like to make that automatically.

How to archive that?
Thanks you for your time.

Here my code:

````
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextEditingController search = TextEditingController();
    FocusNode searchNode = FocusNode();
    return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: 50,
                  width: 400,
                  child: TextField(
                    focusNode: searchNode,
                    controller: search,
                    autofocus: true,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        label: Text("Cerca prodotto...")),
                    onChanged: (val) => _runFilter(val),
                    onSubmitted: (val) async {
                      print(await product.productExists());
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 50,
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 50,
                        width: 200,
                        child: CheckboxListTile(
                          value: autoInsert,
                          title: const Text("Aggiunta automatica"),
                          onChanged: (val){
                            setState(() {
                              autoInsert = val!;
                            });
                          },
                        )
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 50,
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () {},
                            child: const Text("Nuovo prodotto")),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                )
                /**
                 * Il resto qui
                 */

              ],
            )
          ],
        ));
  }

```

I tried with:
searchNode.requestFocus()

Focus.of(context).requestFocus(searchNode) <-- this gives error
````

Comment: `searchNode.requestFocus()`

Comment: aready tried that...

Comment: I would suggest you include options you have tried in the question so the community doesn't recommend something you have already found not to work.